# How MongoDB works with Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

a quick question about how docker and mongo coexist.

1. When I deploy my app to docker hub, does it include db records?
2. When docker removes mongo records. When I stop container, or only when I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is depends...

You could create a image with your records, but that would increase your image size, and if someone mount a volume to the path `/data/db` they would lose your database. So I do not recommend to upload a image with a loaded database, instead use a custom entrypoint script to init your database.

About when the records are destroyed, it will happen when you remove the container, but only if you did not mount a volume to the folder `/data/db` in the container, then the database will be persisted even if you remove the container.

You can see more info about how to use the image at: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/